# Pip removes my python executable (windows)

Tags: python, pip, lxml

When I run `pip install lxml` on my Windows machine, it fails with the following message:

> error: command 'C:\Users\choffman.local\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

This isn't a huge deal, but when I go to my python directory `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4`, `python.exe` is no longer there. How is this possible? The rest of the directories (DLLs, Doc, include, etc) are still in place, but the executable is gone.

I'm able to `pip install` other packages successfully. lxml is the first time I've had this issue. How can the use of a package manager lead to deleting python?

Apologies if this is a duplicate-- it's difficult to search for "pip" and "deletes" without getting a lot of package management questions.